# safari highlighting artifacts when ajax resizes objects above it

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

On Safari 3.2.1, I observe that if a textarea is highlighted as the active control, and an object above it resizes (e.g., an img loads) there are fragments of highlighting left behind after the textarea moves to accommodate the new layout. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Safari. You can probably work around it by triggering a page redraw (like changing the background color slightly), but I think it's best not to use hacks like this to fix a minor browser bug. You could report the bug at Apple and see if it has been fixed in the Safari 4 beta.

Comment: Thanks. It may be a bug in Safari, but I have enough Safari users that I ought to fix it. :/